Can I attach boards horizontally on the face of a shadowbox fence to eliminate the gaps?
I have a shadowbox fence and the dog can get his mouth in the gap and is ripping the boards.  Cedar boards are too expensive to keep changing.  Can I add pine boards (only to the bottom half) to the face of the shadowbox to cover the gaps?  I realize attaching is where the challenge is.  Two have a runner to attach to and top has a runner but suggestions for the other  boards.  Attaching to the existing boards is only about 1" in thickness so not sure how secure it would be and do not want to have screws sticking out the other side.
The new boards are just there for a visual not the ones I'd be using just extra cedar boards I had. Also just seeing how many I would need to get to the middle runner.  I would square up the ends and thinking about using staggered lengths similar to how a wooden floor looks.


A photo would help, and a diagram of what you're suggesting.

Cedar is used outside because it is slow to rot.  Pine(plain) will rot much faster.  You want PT wood or wood that is well covered with stain/paint.  Wood surfaces that are attached/together rot first.

Suggestion: consider using plastic trim for the boards within the dogs reach? Harder than cedar, less toxic than pressure treated? Alternative suggestion: Ask over on the pets stack; someone there may have dealt with this. (Though they may send you back here; it's on the borderline )

Expensive suggestion: tropical rot-resistant hardwood like ipe. Expensive, but impressively durable; we have a boardwalk near my house built of ironwood and outside of its color fading to grey it has shown absolutely no wear. Ipe is so dense that it sinks in water and wears out tools quickly.

@keshlam  I know local(Ontario) ironwood is not big.  Very big is about 6 inches.

It might be more expedient to train the dog to not do "bad" stuff. Lots of ways to approach this, but I am thinking a $250 e-collar off Amazon and a few weeks of vigilance will cure the problem forever. And lead you on a path to have a generally better-behaved pet (you will have a tried-and true method of communicating to your pet when some behavior is not acceptable). Of course, this is the wrong site for pet  training questions, but I bet there is a good one somewhere around here...
Once you stop the destructive behavior, fix the fence one final time as needed.

And if you go the training route: If your dog gets bored and loves to chew, make sure you provide and approved alternative as part of the training. Chewing the fence is bad. Chewing the toy (or bone, or whatever) is good. You are not trying to discipline the dog, just redirect the natural instincts in a good direction.

Definitely see the pets stack for good advice about redirecting unwanted behaviors.

The question for Pets.SE is different from the question here.  There, the question is how to change the behavior of the dog.  Here the question is how to change the configuration of the fence.  It wouldn't be cross-posting to ask about changing the behavior of the dog there and changing the fence here.  That's two different questions.  There may be some overlap in the middle, but there is plenty that would only be appropriate for one stack or the other.

Spray the fence with a bitterant?

If the dog is chewing the accessible sides of the backyard-side fence pickets, the solution is to make those either inaccessible or otherwise uninteresting to chew.
I'd cut more pickets to about half height and the width of the gap between backyard-side pickets, and screw them into the bottom and middle runners with tiny gaps left. It would ruin the shadowbox effect about as bad as the horizontal pickets you have in the picture, but would keep the dog from being able to get teeth on either the new or old pickets.
Unless the dog happens to be a surface chewer; I had a dog that literally ate a piece of MDF siding next to my backdoor somehow. With such dogs the only way is supervision, training, and discouragement.
